# Cannot install Ubuntu SDK on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: apt, software-installation, ubuntu-sdk

I am setting up a Development environment on Ubuntu 13.10 for developing HTML5 App for Ubuntu.

I used the following command to install the Ubuntu SDK

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk
```

Then I found that QTCreator/Ubuntu SDK installed in ubuntu.Also I can  create a HTML5 Tabbed Touch UI Project in Ubuntu SDK. But when I try to run this project from Build-> Run it is giving me following error

```
Starting ubuntu-html5-app-launcher --www=/home/hitech/TestApp
Failed to start program. Path or permissions wrong?
ubuntu-html5-app-launcher exited with code -1
```

Where TestApp is my project name.

I searched on askubuntu.com but not found exactly what is creating a issue. Somewhere I found that dependency of qtcreator and qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu are broken so I tried to install all the component of qtcreator manually. I am using Synaptic Package Manager to manage the packages. In that I install the packaged in following sequence

1) QtCreator - 2.8.1-0ubuntu1~saucy1~test6
2) qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu - 2.8.1.1bzr65saucy0
3) qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-common - 2.8.1.1bzr65saucy0

After that I tried to install qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-cordova but it's dependency is not satisfied and giving me following Error

```
qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-cordova : Depends: qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu (= 2.8.1bzr56saucy0) but 2.8.1.1bzr65saucy0 is to be installed
```

Can you please help to resolve this issue?

I also tried the same installation in Ubuntu Ubuntu 12.04 LTS but the result is same there.

---

**Note**:

This is not a problem of Unmet Dependency, It is a bug in Ubuntu SDK installation that qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu only having one version 2.8.1.1bzr65saucy0 while the qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-cordova is depends on 2.8.1bzr56saucy0 version. The installation of Ubuntu-SDK is not resolving all dependency as it cannot install

Comment: I know how to handle the dependencies but in my case qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-cordova depends on qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu = 2.8.1bzr56saucy0 but I cannot find the version 2.8.1bzr56saucy0 of  qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu. No build available of  qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu 2.8.1bzr56saucy0

Comment: This is not same as Unmet Dependency, It is a bug in Ubuntu SDK installation that qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu only having one version 2.8.1.1bzr65saucy0 while the qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-cordova is depends on 2.8.1bzr56saucy0 version. The installation of Ubuntu-SDK is not resolving all dependency as it cannot install qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-cordova.

Comment: Could you add the complete output? and also `apt-cache policy packages` replacing packages by all the packages involved.

Comment: When I am trying to install apt-get install qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-cordova I am getting following error output `qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-cordova : Depends: qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu (= 2.8.1bzr56saucy0) but 2.8.1.1bzr65saucy0 is to be installed`